# How can I Use HTML code in WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, customizer

**I Would like to use html codes in customizer API. But when I use it, WordPress removes the html tags.**

**In default area I used some html tags, But it does work on my actual page. Is there any way please ?**

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('banner_title_display',array(
        'default' => 'Largest <span> GiveAway</span> collections <small>Online</small>',
        'sanitize_callback' => array($this, 'sanitize_custom_options')

));
$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize,'banner_title_display_control',array(
        'label' => 'Main header text',
        'section' => 'baner_header_section',
        'settings' => 'banner_title_display',
        'type' => 'textarea'

    )));
```